# Replication from AWS RDS to MySQL fails because of unknown character set?

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance running MySQL 5.7, which I have configured as replication master, and a MySQL 5.7 running on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04) as slave. The replication breaks instantly with:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
...
                   Last_Errno: 22
                   Last_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the 
worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 
'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin-changelog.000003, end_log_pos 7106130. See error log 
and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details 
about this failure or others, if any.
...
```

Looking in `performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker`:

```
mysql> select * from replication_applier_status_by_worker\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         CHANNEL_NAME: 
            WORKER_ID: 1
            THREAD_ID: NULL
        SERVICE_STATE: OFF
LAST_SEEN_TRANSACTION: ANONYMOUS
    LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 22
   LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log 
mysql-bin-changelog.000003, end_log_pos 7106130; Error 'Character set '#255' is not a 
compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' 
file' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE USER 'repl'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 
'mysql_native_password' AS '*7D3FD36543D422D3527933EB1921129B72BC7433''
 LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 2021-10-22 15:22:05
```

So, for some reason the master sends something with an unknown character set. Is there any way to fix this? At first I thought it was about collations, and there is indeed no collation with ID=255, but it does clearly say 'character set'. Any ideas?